# jQuery .get in aspx (not using separate HTML)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am experimenting with jquery and json in asp.net in order to get a better idea and implement it in a project.

The code is working as desired when working with a separate html page. But when I try to implement it in a single aspx page the backend processing fails.

Below is a preview:
[image]

Below is my code:

in HTML page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var textBoxes = $('input[type="text"]');
            textBoxes.keyup(function () {
                var helpDiv = $(this).attr('id');
                var textInBox = $(this).val();
                $.get('jQuery_Ajax_json', { HelpTextKey: textInBox }, function (response) {
                    $('#' + helpDiv + 'HelpDiv').html(response.Text);
                }, 'json');
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input id="firstName" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="firstNameHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input id="lastName" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="lastNameHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input id="email" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="emailHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Income</td>
            <td><input id="income" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="incomeHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
         CodeBehind="jQuery_Ajax_json.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.jQuery_Ajax_json" %>
```

In aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class jQuery_Ajax_json : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string JSONString = js.Serialize(GetHelpTextByKey(Request["HelpTextKey"]));

            Response.Write(JSONString);
        }

        private HelpText GetHelpTextByKey(string key)
        {
            HelpText helpText = new HelpText();

                helpText.Key = key;
                helpText.Text = key.ToUpper();

            return helpText;
        }
    }

    public class HelpText
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to totally eliminate the HTML page and work with just aspx and aspx.cs. I appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Here is my take:

aspx file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="jQuery_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="folder_manage_system.jQuery_test" %>


<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title> </title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var textBoxes = $('input[type="text"]');
            textBoxes.keyup(function () {
                var helpDiv = $(this).attr('id');
                var textInBox = $(this).val();
                $.get('jQuery_test', { HelpTextKey: textInBox }, function (response) {
                    $('#' + helpDiv + 'HelpDiv').html(response.Text);
                }, 'json');
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input id="firstName" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="firstNameHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input id="lastName" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="lastNameHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input id="email" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="emailHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Income</td>
            <td><input id="income" type="text" /></td>
            <td><div id="incomeHelpDiv"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>






    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace folder_manage_system
    {
        public partial class jQuery_test : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string JSONString = js.Serialize(GetHelpTextByKey(Request["HelpTextKey"]));

                Response.Write(JSONString);
            }

            private HelpText GetHelpTextByKey(string key)
            {
                HelpText helpText = new HelpText();
                if (key != null)
                {
                    helpText.Key = key;
                    helpText.Text = key.ToUpper();
                }
                return helpText;
            }
        }
        public class HelpText
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Resulting preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<!DOCTYPE html>` after the page declaration as:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="jQuery_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="folder_manage_system.jQuery_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: tried it but it does not seem to solve the issue. I now added this: if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string JSONString = js.Serialize(GetHelpTextByKey(Request["HelpTextKey"]));

                Response.Write(JSONString);
            }  and got rid of the json string being printed on the page as soon as it loads. Now even the jquery is running on keyup but it does not seem to enter the anonymous function to write the output in helpDiv.